# Lacie Internet Space NAS factory reset?

Tags: nas, reset, lacie

I'm refurbishing a Lacie Internet Space NAS 1TB White. It only have one button at the back and a blue light in front. I'm searching everywhere to find the factory reset instruction for this specific model but cant find it. Already read it's user manual but nothing about factory reset.
Someone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this procedure? https://www.lacie.com/gb/en/support/kb/can-i-reset-my-network-drive-to-its-factory-settings-007317en/

Comment: Hi. thanks but that instructions are for another model and already tried without success. any more ideas?

Comment: Turn off the drive. Once its has shut down completely, turn it on. Before the light in the front comes on, flip the power button off and on a few times quickly. You will see the light on the front flashing in a different pattern than normal if it has been reset (very quick pulse that lasts about 1-2 seconds). Normally you'll see 7 flashes that take about 3-5 seconds if it wasn't reset.

Comment: Hi. Will try that Thanks!